# My flair is replaced with a link, is this a bug?

Tags: support, flair

What happened to my flair, it is replace by a link as shown below

[image]

Comment: I see the flair.  Chrome, latest.  Firefox, IE9 also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser displays the link because the image failed to load.

It is either an error local to you or a temporary glitch, I see your flair fine (image URL copied from your profile):

[image: Your flair]

Comment: Thanx its resolved after clearing cache and cookies and restarting of firefox.